# Importing modules in Python that use local paths

Tags: python, path, python-import

I have an issue with a module that uses relative paths, the issue is rather simple to explain:

This is my architecture:

```
myProject/
├───main.py
│
├───modules/
│   ├───__init__.py
│   ├───files/
│   │    some_text.txt
│   └───module.py
```

some_text.txt contains some non-relevant text.

**module.py** contains:

```
def read_file():
    with open("files/some_text.txt","r") as f:
        print(f.read())
```

and **main.py** contains:

```
from modules import module

module.read_file()
```

When I run **main.py**, you can obviously expect this error I get:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'files/some_text.txt'
```

The solution is of course to change the path in **module.py** to "*modules/files/some_text.txt*" but I really don't like this solution because it's not intuitive and won't work if I call directly module.py. Also, if I call myProject from another project, it will still fail because I will have to change the path again to "*myProject/modules/files/some_text.txt*".

What are the good practices to solve this problem correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `__file__` variable (that holds the path to the current script) as a root and build your path based on that.

In your case

```
"files/some_text.txt"
# can become
os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'files', 'some_text.txt')
```